# Replacing a JavaScript string in the last occurrence of two tildes ~~

Tags: javascript, string, split, splice

I have a String which looks like this:

```
Mon Jan 24 2022 09:28:10 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~00-Entwurf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~~~
Mon Jan 24 2022 09:28:20 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~00-Entwurf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~~~
Tue Jan 25 2022 20:51:17 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~Comment 1~~
Tue Jan 25 2022 20:58:34 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~Comment 2~~
```

What I'm struggling with is the following:

Between the last occurrence of tildes (~~) we have `Comment 2`.
I want to replace that value with another value, for instance `Comment 3`.

My solution would be this: https://jsfiddle.net/13wrpa2b/

```
alert(str[19]) // Comment 2

str[19] = "Comment 3"; 

let concat = str.join('~~');
alert(concat);
```

The problem with that is that I don't always know the exact length of the log and the comment does not necessarily have to be in the 19th place. But I do know that it will always be between the last occurrence of tildes ~~.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are two tildes at the end of the string the array will look like `[..., "Comment 2", ""]`. Therefore the item is in the second to last position so instead of using `19` you can use `str.length - 2`.

```js
let str = 'Mon Jan 24 2022 09:28:10 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~00-Entwurf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~~~ Mon Jan 24 2022 09:28:20 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~00-Entwurf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~~~ Tue Jan 25 2022 20:51:17 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~Comment 1~~ Tue Jan 25 2022 20:58:34 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~Comment 2~~'.split('~~')

console.log(str[str.length - 2]) // Comment 2

str[str.length - 2] = "Comment 3"; 

let concat = str.join('~~');
console.log(concat);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
const arr = logentry.split('~~');
arr[arr.length-2] = 'My custom stuff'; // this is now the last block in the line
const updatedLine = arr.join('~~'));
alert(updatedLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex: `/(?<=~~)[^~]+(?=~~$)/gm`

This creates a lookbehind and lookahead for words at the end of the line wrapped by two tildes `~~`

(If you want the last in the whole string instead of last in the line, remove the `gm` at the end)

```js
const regex = /(?<=~~)[^~]+(?=~~$)/gm;

const str = `
log: Mon Jan 24 2022 09:28:10 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~00-Entwurf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~~~
Mon Jan 24 2022 09:28:20 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~00-Entwurf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~~~
Tue Jan 25 2022 20:51:17 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~Comment 1~~
Tue Jan 25 2022 20:58:34 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~Comment 2~~
`;

console.log(str.match(regex))
console.log(str.replace(regex, 'replacement'))
```

---

Of course, you can even choose the replacement based on the selection with:

```js
str.replace(regex, selection => selection == 'Comment 2' ? 'Comment 3' : 'Comment 4')
```

---

Extending this with the case of incrementing the number (in case you need to):

```js
str.replace(regex, selection => selection.replace(/\d+/, n => +n+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace with a regular expression.

```js
const
    string = 'Mon Jan 24 2022 09:28:10 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~00-Entwurf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~~~\nMon Jan 24 2022 09:28:20 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~00-Entwurf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~~~\nTue Jan 25 2022 20:51:17 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~Comment 1~~\nTue Jan 25 2022 20:58:34 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)~~Admin_SA, SharePoint (i:0#.w|xespsa)~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~15-Indirekter Einkauf~~Comment 2~~',
    result = string.replace(/(?<=~~)[^~]+(?=~~$)/gm, 'Comment3');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In sake of simplicity you could try:

```
str.replace(/~~Comment 2~~$/, "~~Comment 3~~");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).